# JAXB XmlElement Annotation convert from String to int

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, annotations

I am receiving XML via a web service, and I am parsing the XML into Java using the XmlElement Annotation.  Here is how I am using the annotations.  Please let me know if I am using them correctly.  I am particularly interested in the int field.  It seems to be working, but I feel like I am not using the annotations correctly.  I see a lot of examples similar to @XmlElement(name="something" type=Integer.class).  Is this type attribute also advised on the XmlJavaTypeAdapter annotation?  I apologize for the long list of questions, this is my first time using the XmlElement annotations, and I want to make sure I'm doing it right.  Thank you in advance for any help.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Person")
public class Person {
    @XmlElement(name="FirstName")
    public String firstName = "";

    @XmlElement(name="LastName")
    public String lastName="";

    @XmlElement(name="Age")
    public int age = 0;

    @XmlElement(name="BirthDate")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateAdapter.class)
    public Date birthDate = new Date(0);
}


public class DateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Date> {
    private static final DateFormat FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    @Override
    public String marshal(Date date) throws Exception {
        return (date == null) ? "" : FORMAT.format(date);
    }

    @Override
    public Date unmarshal(String str) throws Exception {
        return FORMAT.parse(str);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion your solution is correct.

However, you may need to replace `int` with `Integer` if the Age element may contain `null` (you should check Person element's definition in the XSD file (if it is a web service you can find the xsd in the wsdl file)).

Comment: Age cannot be null, but I am afraid of it coming across as an empty tag <Age/>.  Will this take the default value that I have entered (0).

Comment: If the Age element's definition contains at least one of the following attributes: minOccurs="1" nillable="false" it cannot be empty and if you validate the xml file (and you should validate the file), the validation will throw an exception.